# If one block in the nether is 8 blocks in the overworld, does that make the nether smaller than the overworld?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The title says it all: If one block in the nether is 8 blocks in the overworld, does that make the nether smaller than the overworld?

I was reading a question about portal science and i was wondering if the nether is smaller than the overworld?

How does this effect portal linking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No.** The world border is the same in both the Overworld and the Nether, so you can access the same amount of land. Although, in normal gameplay, this will not be noticeable(`60000000` blocks is a lot!). Executing `/worldborder get` in both dimensions returns the same result in both dimensions, even if you change the worldborder. Both dimensions are the same size, and big enough to the point that no survival player will(probably) ever get there.

Comment: But that should mean that if someone makes a portal at the worldborder in the nether that they will spawn far outside the worldborder of the overworld. Or did the mojang guys think of that? Also wasn't the worldborderraised to 30.000.000 blocks instead of 6.000.000?

Comment: I tested a brand new world in Minecraft 1.8.9 and used `/worldborder get` to get the worldborder, and it said `60000000`. Maybe it changed in 1.9, but I was testing in 1.8.9. Also, in my testing, I haven't seen an instance where a portal spawns outside the border.

Comment: Ignore half of my comment there, `60000000` is 60,000,000, bigger than 30,000,000

Comment: @BRHSM I just tested that. If you create a portal at the world border in the nether (at 29,999,990), it will create a portal about 100 blocks inside the world border in the overworld. Using this overworld portal creates another portal in the nether around 3,750,000, which is 30,000,000/8.

Comment: The `/worldborder get` returns the width of the world border. That's why you get the 60M. The coords go from -30M to +30M, centred at 0, by default. Nice test btw, @MrLemon.

Comment: @Ghalid, +1, but it's not correct to say that the dimensions are theoretically infinite. The precision of 64 bit floating point limits the maximum size to not much more than the default world border, even if a world border didn't exist.

Comment: @ire_and_curses By that, I meant infinite to the point that no survival player will probably ever get there, but I probably worded it wrong. I'll edit it.

Comment: @MrLemon so making a base at 29.999.990 will mean that you cant have a nether portal there that leads you back to the same place

Comment: @BRHSM: It seems any nether portal beyond about 3.75M will lead to the same place, around 30M in the overworld, and any base in the nether beyond about 3.75M is unreachable by direct portal from the overworld.